# Not being able to run my python scripts that contain third-party modules using Win+R command

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to run my code using <kbd>Win+R</kbd>.
I am able to run a python script without using third-party modules. But when I use some third-party module in my code it shows this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pkgar\Desktop\Newfolder\pw.py", line 6, in <module>
    import sys,pyperclip
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyperclip'
```

Edit: I am able to run the code in VS code, but I am just curious how to run the code using Win+R command.It is running perfectly using Win+R command when I don't use pyperclip module at all.

Comment: Run `pip install pyperclip` in the cmd / make sure you are activating any virtual environment you have installed the library in.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to activate virtual environment in windows?

Comment: Find your virtual environment folder, should be near (just inside or outside) your project directory, In the cmd type `<path-to-venv-folder-name>\scripts\activate`. Then from the same cmd run your python program.

Comment: It may sound naive, can you tell me where this project directory is?

Comment: It is the directory / folder of your project / code.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't installed pyperclip yet.

you can install it using `pip install pyperclip` on your cmd.

check this out

https://pypi.org/project/pyperclip/

and olso if pip itself hasn't installed yet use

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: But I have already installed it because when I hit "pip list" on cmd, it shows up there.

Comment: hummm . open a new file and just put `import pyperclip` see if it gives the same error or not.

Comment: so use `pip uninstall pyperclip` and then reinstall it again.